# Boolean Function in ada 'procedure or entry name expected' 'invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call'

Tags: ada

I am stuck on my ada program which is supposed to for loop through an array and return true for the number of 100 in the list. I am having trouble getting my code to compile without errors, i am brand new to ada and also ada boolean functions. If someone could help point me in the right direction I would seriously appreciate it

```
with Gnat.Io; use Gnat.Io;
procedure Arr is

type ArrayType is array (Integer range<>) of Integer;

    Array1 : ArrayType := (45, 100, 75, 32, 99, 66, 82);
    Array2 : ArrayType := (67, 78, 89, 97, 45);
    Array3 : ArrayType := (1,2);

function HasPerfectScore (theArray : ArrayType) return Boolean is
begin
    for I in Array1'Range loop
       if I = 100 then
            Put("Perfect score = (I)");
       else
            Array1(I=I+1);
       end if;

    end loop;
return Boolean;
end HasPerfectScore;
begin
    null;
end Arr;
```

Comment: There are several problems with this program. Please provide exact list of compiler errors with your question

Comment: You cannot say ‘return Boolean’ as a statement. Boolean is a type and not a value. True and False are Boolean values

Comment: I am sorry to say that you lack of basic understanding of function in Ada. Even we help you with the code, you may not understand it unless you understand the basic. First, it is function parameter.  Second, it is the function return (True or False). Third, it is about actual parameter passing.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you do not understand the comments you received. Here is a program that does what you want to do.

```ada
-------------------------------------------------------------
-- Indicate whether or not an array of integers contains
-- the value 100
-------------------------------------------------------------

with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Nums is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;

   function contains_100 (Arr : Nums) return Boolean is
      Result : Boolean := False;
   begin
      for I in Arr'Range loop
         if Arr(I) = 100 then
            Result := True;
         end if;
      end loop;
      return Result;
   end contains_100;

   Num_Elements : Positive;
begin
   Put ("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
   Get (Num_Elements);

   declare
      Sample : Nums (1 .. Num_Elements);
   begin
      Put_Line ("Enter the" & Num_Elements'Image & " values:");
      for I in Sample'Range loop
         Get (Sample(I));
      end loop;
      
      if contains_100 (Sample) then
         Put_Line ("The array contains the value 100.");
      else
         Put_Line ("The array does not contain the value 100.");
      end if;
   end;

end Main;
```

The function named contains_100 takes a parameter of the type Nums, which is an unconstrained array type. This means that the array passed to the function contains_100 can be any size, but it will have a definite size as we will see further on in the program.

The function contains_100 returns a Boolean value, which must be either True or False. The function declares a local variable named Result. Result is a Boolean initialized to False because at this point in the function we have not found the value 100 in the array.
The for loop iterates through all the values in the parameter Arr, comparing each value in turn to the number 100. If the value equals 100 the local variable Result is assigned the value True. After the loop completes the local variable Result will either be False because we never encountered the value 100 or it will be True because the array contains at least one element with the value 100. The value of Result is returned.

This program gets the values for the array from user input. We must know how many values the user wants to input so that we can make an array of the correct size. The local variable Num_Elements will hold the number of elements the user wants to enter.

The user is prompted to enter the number of elements in the array. The Get procedure from Ada.Integer_Text_IO inputs the user's response and places the value in the variable Num_Elements.

The program now needs to create an array containing Num_Elements, but we are now in the executable portion of the procedure Main where we cannot declare variables. The simple answer is to create a new code block within main beginning with the reserved word "declare". The reserved word "declare" creates a new declarative region allowing the creation of an array named Sample with exactly Num_Elements elements.

A new executable portion of the internal code block begins and the user is prompted to enter the Num_Elements values into the array.

The for loop then calls Get to input a value in each element of the array Sample.

Finally, an "if" condition is executed, calling contains_100 and passing in the local variable Sample. If contains_100 returns True then the program outputs a message stating that the array does contain the value 100. If contains_100 returns False the program outputs a message stating that the array does not contain the value 100.

Following are some examples of executing the program:

```
Enter the number of elements in the array: 3
Enter the 3 values:
-100 0 9
The array does not contain the value 100.

Enter the number of elements in the array: 8
Enter the 8 values:
1 2 3 4 5 100 6 7
The array contains the value 100.
```

**Edit:** In response to the discussion concerning the use of a quantified expression the program above can be simplified to the following.

```ada
-------------------------------------------------------------
-- Indicate whether or not an array of integers contains
-- the value 100
-------------------------------------------------------------

with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Nums is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;

   Num_Elements : Positive;
begin
   Put ("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
   Get (Num_Elements);

   declare
      Sample : Nums (1 .. Num_Elements);
   begin
      Put_Line ("Enter the" & Num_Elements'Image & " values:");
      for I in Sample'Range loop
         Get (Sample (I));
      end loop;

      if (for some I of sample => I = 100) then
         Put_Line ("The array contains the value 100.");
      else
         Put_Line ("The array does not contain the value 100.");
      end if;
   end;

end Main;
```

Comment: Nowadays, the entire body of `contains_100` could be `is (for some E of Arr => E = 100);`

Comment: Simon Wright
I realize that, but the original author is very new to programming and is still thinking in terms of explicit looping. In fact the entire function can be deleted and the quantified expression can replace the function call.